# Flutter - How to use the recommended word function on the keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard

I want to add a words recommendation function when the user uses the keyboard. The example in the picture is the function I want. It is a function of Instagram membership. Which function of the plotter should I use to add this function? Thank you so much for the hint or the answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function of  `ListView.builder()` with a horizontal scroll, and call the function for `onTap:` of `TextField()`